# Debian 8. Удаление графического интерфейса

Tags: debian, администрирование

"По наследству" досталась виртуальная машина с установленным на ней Debian 8. И все бы хорошо, только вот не нужен мне графический интерфейс. С linux дела мало имел. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно его удалить или отключить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удаление начать можно с деинсталляции пакета `xserver-xorg-core`:

```
$ sudo aptitude -y remove xserver-xorg-core
```

а вот для отключения необходимо знать, кто запускает `xserver`. скорее всего, это делает *desktop manager*. эту функцию может выполнять много пакетов. найти тот, что установлен в системе можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ aptitude search '~i~Px-display-manager'
```

пример вывода:

```
i   xdm                                          - X display manager
```

вот его и надо отключить, чтоб не запускался при старте системы:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d xdm disable
```