# графическая оболочка ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Стала потребность отключить графическую оболочку ubuntu, но не знаю как это сделать. Знаю что на Win7 есть исполняемый файл explorer.exe, мы его удаляем и графическая оболочка исчезает, есть ли подобный файл в linux?

Answer (score 3):

В Windows вы не можете достигнуть отключения графической оболочки путём удаления explorer.exe. Я вообще не уверен, что его там возможно отключить.

В Ubuntu можете воспользоваться сочетанием <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: В Windows можно. Вы можете указать свой Shell, а в нём хоть explorer.exe (по умолчанию), хоть консольное приложение.

Comment: {HKLM,HKCU}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете выйти в "жесткую" консоль с помощью клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>; В ней вам придется заново ввести логин и пароль пользователя. Эта консоль полезна для случаев, когда графическая оболочка каким-то образом сломана и нуждается, например, в перезагрузке.

Вернуться обратно можно с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (иногда <kbd>F8</kbd>)

Если вам нужен сервер полностью без графической оболочки (это полезно для экономии ресурсов, например), то можно просто сразу установить систему соответствующим образом. Либо переконфигурируйте имеющуюся:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457413/178576
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430985/178576

(спасибо alexander barakin за дополнение)

---

Подтверждаю сомнения LEQADA: в Windows нет возможности установить систему вообще без графической оболочки, но можно загрузиться в безопасном режиме только с командной строкой. Удаление explorer.exe не приведет ни к чему хорошему.

Comment: *то нужно просто сразу установить систему соответствующим образом* — необязательно. [ссылка1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457413/178576), [ссылка2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430985/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: спасибо, вы как всегда эксперт. Исправил ответ.

Comment: я только учусь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: все бы так учились )